# Write a CSV file asynchronously in Python

Tags: python, csv, async-await, python-asyncio, fastapi

I am writing a CSV file with the following function:

```py
import csv
import os
import aiofiles


async def write_extract_file(output_filename: str, csv_list: list):
    """
    Write the extracted content into the file
    """
    try:
        async with aiofiles.open(output_filename, "w+") as csv_file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=columns.keys())
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows(csv_list)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Output file not present", output_filename)
        print("Current dir: ", os.getcwd())
        raise FileNotFoundError
```

However, as there is no await allowed over `writerows` method, there are no rows being written into the CSV file.
How to resolve this issue? Is there any workaround available?
Thank you.
Entire code can be found [here](https://github.com/OdiaNLP/WhatsAppExtractor/blob/62e8c68c59882ec3c71b38f93a390efcadacb99a/wextractor/extractor.py#L107).

Comment: note that using async io for local files tends to be slower than synchronous io.  you're probably off just using a sync (i.e. non-async) method and wrapping in `loop.run_in_executor` so that the async code can interact with it nicely

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion it’s better not to try to use the `aiofiles` with the `csv` module and run the synchronous code using `loop.run_in_executor` and wait it asynchronously like below:

```
def write_extract_file(output_filename: str, csv_list: list):
    """
    Write the extracted content into the file
    """
    try:
        with open(output_filename, "w+") as csv_file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=columns.keys())
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows(csv_list)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Output file not present", output_filename)
        print("Current dir: ", os.getcwd())
        raise FileNotFoundError


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, write_extract_file, 'test.csv', csv_list)
```

Comment: note that this runs `write_extract_file` synchronously.  you need to use `await loop.run_in_executor(None, write_extract_file, 'test.csv', csv_list)` to actually run it asynchronously

Comment: The problem with this approach is if you need to perform async operations in the middle of writing the csv

Answer (score 7):

You can use [aiocsv](https://pypi.org/project/aiocsv/). Here is a quick example of writing a row to a CSV file asynchronously:

```
import asyncio
import aiofiles
from aiocsv import AsyncWriter

async def main():
    async with aiofiles.open('your-path.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = AsyncWriter(f)
        await writer.writerow(['name', 'age'])
        await writer.writerow(['John', 25])

asyncio.run(main())
```

For more examples follow: https://pypi.org/project/aiocsv/

Answer (score 0):

You can use aiofiles, you just gotta convert the dict to a row :)

```
import aiofiles

async def write_extract_file(
    output_filename: str, csv_list: list
):

    cols = columns.keys()

    async with aiofiles.open(output_filename, mode='w+') as f_out:

        await f_out.write(','.join(cols)+'\n')

        for data in csv_list:

            line = []

            for c in cols:
                line.append(str(data[c]) if c in data else '')

            line = ','.join(line) + '\n'
    
            await f_out.write(line)
```

Comment: This code doesn't handle a lot of the logic that the csv module is performing, like quoting columns that have commas in them for example.